How to plan several shape in a graph?
This is kind of a algorithm problem.
Here is a map that is a bounded rectangular multiconnected region sized m*n, Due to different terrain factors within the map, each grid has a different cost. Cost of terrain "river" is Infinity since it is considered to be unusable, of terrain "hill" is 10,and of "plain" is 1. And there are several grid marked as Mine which could provide mineral.
This class can be defined like following:
class MyMap {
  private _data: number[][];
  private _mine: [number, number][];
  constructor(width: number, height: number) {
    this._data = Array.from({ length: height }, () => Array(width).fill(0));
    this._mine = [];
  }

  getMine() {
    return this._mine;
  }

  setMine(mine: [number, number]) {
    this._mine.push(mine);
    this._data[mine[1]][mine[0]] = Infinity;
  }

  setCost(x: number, y: number, cost: number) {
    this._data[y][x] = cost;
  }

  getCost(x: number, y: number) {
    return this._data[y][x];
  }
}

Now, there are several factories supposed to be planned in this map, each factory comes with different shape and area, shape and area are not allowed to be changed, while you can change their direction. For example, these two factories are regarded as same:

We need to find a plan to locate several specified factories on the map and plan a road network so that all factories are connected to the mines, and the total cost of factories and roads occupation is minimized.
I think this problem might be solved by DP, but I've no progress by now.
Really APPRECIATE for your comments @Dave.
This is a simple example with 2 mines in the map and 2 factories to be placed. And this is only "plane" terrain in this map, but all 3 terrains may appear in other question.

Cost of this map is 32, 17 come from road network, 15 come from factories. It is obviously not the optimal, while the optimal result should be like this:

7 cost from road network and 15 from factories. The optimal cost is 22.
And of course there the rules about connecting factories to different mines which I'm sorry for not clarifying at very beginning. Every factory has at least 1 gate, when at least 1 gate connected to road network, this factory is considered to connected to the road network. Or the gate can connect to factory which already connect to the network, for example F3 and F4 in the following map.

Since mine takes only 1 grid in the map, just 1 of 8 grid around the mine is road, this mine is considered to connected to road network.
I don't know the time complexity to reach a absolute-optimal solution, I assume a near-optimal solution is acceptable.
Hope my poor English did not confuse you.

Would a near-optimal solution suffice? Also, are we minimizing building costs or travel costs? I.e., is the cost the sum of the cost of terrain occupied by factories/roads, or the sum of cost of the roads between factories & the nearest mine, or the sum of cost between every factory/mine pairing, or something else?

Could you give a very simple map, with factories placed (not necessarily optimally) and the cost for that map?

Are there any rules about connecting factories to different mines?

Thanks for your comments, I've update this question to answer your comments.

This reminds me of bin-packing?

I dont’t think it’s possible to find most optimal solution in polynomial time, unless using linear programming.
Suppose you already have the factories placed on the map, then finding the shortest paths is easy. It’s a simple BFS.
The hard part is to find the optimal placement of the factories. There is exponentially many possibilities and there is no way to try all of them in polynomial time. Maybe try some heuristic approach how to traverse the factory placements.
You can define a neighbour for some factory placement, e.g. by moving one factory in a certain dimension by one square or rotating one factory. Then, start from random factory placement, try all neighbours and evaluate them. That should be easy, since for factory placement finding the paths is just BFS as I stated before. Which neigbours to choose can be decided by some heuristic. You can take a look at Tabu search or Simulated annealing. These are usually very efficient for these types of discrete optimization problems and are quite easy to implement. I would also recommend hill climb search to try first. Hill climb search just simply chooses the best neighbour all the time, converging to some local optima. The cost function which to minimize is of course the cost of the paths.
This is a heuristic approach and it will be able to find good solutions by its up to experimentation to see how good the solutions are.
Different approach will be to map this problem as a linear programming problem. If you achieve that, I think you are then able to find global optimum in polynomial time.
